# how to convert string to tuple in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a string that i get from parameter-file.json the parameter can be accessed using $param

```
$param='abc|cde|ghi'
```

i need to iterate through this param variable

codes that i have tried

> following code has the error of "mismatched input \u0027.\u0027 expecting RIGHT_PAREN"

```
A= STRSPLIT($param,'\\x7c');
B=FOREACH A GENERATE 1
STORE A into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

> following code has the error of "mismatched input \u0027.\u0027 expecting RIGHT_PAREN"

```
A= STRSPLIT($param,'|');
B=FOREACH A GENERATE 1
STORE B into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

> following code has the error of ""Error during parsing. \u003cfile , line 7\u003e Cannot expand macro \u0027STRSPLIT\u0027. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion."

```
A= STRSPLIT('$param','|');
B=FOREACH A GENERATE 1
STORE B into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

> following code has the error of ""Error during parsing. \u003cfile , line 7\u003e Cannot expand macro \u0027STRSPLIT\u0027. Reason: Macro must be defined before expansion."

```
A= STRSPLIT('$param','\\x7c');
B=FOREACH A GENERATE 1
STORE B into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

> following code has the error of "":"Error during parsing. \u003cline 7, column 120\u003e Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near \u0027bytearrayy\u0027""

```
A = LOAD '$userQuery' USING PigStorage('|') AS (name:bytearrayy);
B=FOREACH A GENERATE 1
STORE B into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

> following code has the error of ""Error during parsing. \u003cline 7, column 9\u003e mismatched input \u0027.\u0027 expecting QUOTEDSTRING"""

```
A = LOAD $userQuery USING PigStorage('|') AS (name:bytearrayy);
B=FOREACH A GENERATE 1
STORE B into '$output' using PigStorage(',');
```

any suggestions on how to achieve the required task.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pig` udf's should be used in relational operators like `FOREACH`.

```
A = LOAD 'a.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (name:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE STRSPLIT(name,'\\x7c') AS names;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE names.$0,names.$1,names.$2 ;
DUMP C;
```

Above sample code which is reading from local file a.txt,

```
a|b|c
x|y|z
p|q|r
```

executing using local `pig -x local test1.pig`

results output as

```
(a,b,c)
(x,y,z)
(p,q,r)
```

And also, please note that, pig error messages are little misleading, in your code 
`B=FOREACH A GENERATE 1 is not ending with semicolon ";"`

Comment: Okay , even with the ';' i get the same error. And i don't want to read from the file , i have it in as a variable with $param as its name.

Comment: I recommend, you use shell script and get the filename using shell cmds to split etc, call pig inside the script with file name as param. pig is not generic language like java/c, as i said all the udfs have to be applied on the data.